# Discord Bot Java - I'm trying to have my bot send a message every so often and need help on which event listener is best suited

Tags: java, discord-jda

I want my bot to send a message randomly throughout the day.
I was using the onMessageReceived event to achieve this, but that depends on a user sending a message, and I want the bot to still send a message randomly even if there hasn't been any server activity for a while.

**Basically, what I'm hoping to find is if there's an Event Listener that fires every few seconds consistently while the bot is online**. The event shouldn't be dependent on if users send messages or if people join voice channels, etc.

Does anyone know of an Event Listener that could help me achieve this?

Comment: That doesn't sound like an event.  That sounds like a job for an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) or [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long))

Answer (score 1):

Just use a timer in your bot after you run a command, you could add a command like !motd random for a random interval and then if you wanted to do it after a certain period of time do !motd 3hours